# scanf and format related?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file with the following content

```
"AAA";"BBB"
```

I try to extract the 2 columns this way :

```
char v1[50];
char v2[50];
int ret = fscanf(fp, "\"%s\";\"%s\"", v1, v2);
```

But it returns 1 and everything in 'v1' !

Is it normal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `"%s"` format reads *space delimited* strings. It will read the input until it hits a white-space or the end of the input.

You could possibly use the `"%["` format here, maybe something like

```
fscanf(fp, "\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\"", v1, v2);
```

See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information.